# How Can I Rewrite the MySQL Query

Tags: mysql, performance

I have below query, I am trying to rewrite it to improve the performance , what approach i can use to rewrite it.

```
select 
    notes.id, notes.name, notes.parent_type, notes.contact_id from notes 
JOIN 
    ( 
    SELECT contact_id as id from accounts_contacts where account_id = 'acct1876' and deleted = '0' union 
    SELECT quote_id as id from quotes_accounts where account_id = 'acct1876' and deleted = '0' union 
    SELECT opportunity_id as id from accounts_opportunities where account_id = 'acct1876' and deleted = '0' union 
    SELECT leads.id as id from leads where account_id = 'acct1876' and deleted = '0' union 
    SELECT  project_id as id from projects_accounts where account_id = 'acct1876' and deleted = '0' union 
    select 'acct1876' as id 
    ) A 
    ON A.id = notes.parent_id and deleted = '0' OR contact_id in 
    ( SELECT contact_id from accounts_contacts where account_id = 'acct1876' and deleted = '0' ) and deleted = '0' 

    group by notes.id;
```

Comment: You could learn about JOINs, but it's really unclear what you're actually trying to do here !?!?!

Comment: It would help a lot if you could explain your requirement rather than hoping people on SO will correctly reverse-engineer it from your query.  Also, you are misusing `GROUP BY`; there are no aggregating functions (like `SUM()` or `GROUP_CONCAT()`) in your query.

Comment: Basically the query is slow. Indexing is OK but over all performance is not good. I am trying to restructure the query to produce the same output.

Comment: You could start by normalizing your database properly.

Answer (score 1):

First, your final OR is a duplicate of the start of your inner join and otherwise pointless.

This part

```
  ON A.id = notes.parent_id 
  and deleted = '0' 
  OR contact_id in ( SELECT contact_id 
                       from accounts_contacts 
                       where account_id = 'acct1876' 
                       and deleted = '0' ) 
  and deleted = '0'
```

can just be

```
  ON A.id = notes.parent_id
```

Next, it appears you are trying to get all IDs associated with a given account, including the account in question.  I would make sure each of those tables has an index on the account ID AND Deleted columns.  Also, for this query, I would have it as DISTINCT to prevent duplicates being joined to the notes table.  I would then swap the order (for me, mentally query the IDs you want, THEN get the notes associated). Below are covering indexes for each table of your UNION query, plus the notes table by the joined parent ID column.

```
table                  index
accounts_contacts      (account_id, deleted, contact_id)
quotes_accounts        (account_id, deleted, quote_id )
accounts_opportunities (account_id, deleted, opportunity_id )
leads                  (account_id, deleted, id
projects_accounts      (account_id, deleted, project_id )
notes                  (parent_id)
```

Now, the minor updated query

```
select 
      notes.id, 
      notes.name, 
      notes.parent_type, 
      notes.contact_id 
   from 
         (SELECT DISTINCT contact_id as id 
             from accounts_contacts 
             where account_id = 'acct1876' and deleted = '0' 
          union 
          SELECT quote_id as id 
             from quotes_accounts 
             where account_id = 'acct1876' and deleted = '0' 
          union 
          SELECT opportunity_id as id 
             from accounts_opportunities 
             where account_id = 'acct1876' and deleted = '0' 
          union 
          SELECT leads.id as id 
             from leads 
             where account_id = 'acct1876' and deleted = '0' 
          union 
          SELECT project_id as id 
             from projects_accounts 
             where account_id = 'acct1876' and deleted = '0' 
          union 
          select 'acct1876' as id ) A 
         JOIN Notes
            ON A.id = notes.parent_id 
   group by 
     notes.id;
```

As one noted, you have a group by, but no sum or aggregate on the columns which will result in the first entry found for such to be included, and since by what appears an auto-incremented ID column, would have the same value no matter where the account "ID" originated from.

Answer (score 0):

To answer your question AND boost performance, I'd like to suggest an approach that may seem weird at first sight.

If you have a reasonable number of records, use MORE SELECTS, not a single (and heavy) one.  You can collect IDs in an array, or (preferably) in a string, then make another query with the id list separated by commas, etc.  This (while it sounds complete nonsense) has many advantages vs virtually no drawbacks: separate SELECTs run fast, then let the db server breathe. When you do one SELECT, other tables won't be locked (!!!) while one big select will lock ALL the tables involved for the whole time of the query.  So it's easier and more readable to do this:

```
$idlist = fetch_idlist("select id from users where name like 'John%'");
$result = fetch_all("select * from mails where userid in ($idlist)");
```

than this:

```
$result = fetch_all("select * from mails left join users on users.id=mails.userid ....")
```

I hope the meaning is clear despite of the nonexistent functions. It's only the principle.  So in your case, maybe you'd like to select contacts, build the id list, then do a separate query for the notes, etc., and compose the final result in php.

Again, this only works with under-a-million record counts, you can't afford to eat up all memory at very high amounts.  But the point is: at high loads, it's incomparably better to to time-consuming queries separately and let other processes fit in between than to lock a whole bunch of tables for a (relatively) long time.

Sorry if it's not 100% of an answer but I thought it was worth to explain.